# JQuery events not always firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a full AJAX app. When I load a new AJAX element, I use callbacks to set handlers on it. To be sure not to be trying to bind a non yet exisiting element, I put the listener on some parent. For example I do this :

```
$el.on( 'click',"#popin a.closePopin", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        closePopin(); 
});
```

This works... 80% percent of time.

My question is, what about the other 20% when nothing is fired?

Thanks.

EDIT : After reading the first answer and comment, I want to precise that the issue is happening randomly on the same elements without updating the code. And $el is a fixe container which never changes or disapear, also the ajax content is necessarly descendant of it.

Comment: The other 20% is probably due to elements not being descendants of $el, or $el being replaced by javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this you should not attach the delegated event to `$el` thus making only descendant elements matching the selector fire the event but rather attach it to `document`.

```
$(document).on('click', "#popin a.closePopin", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    closePopin(); 
});
```

Comment: Despite the fact that binding $(document) instead of any other parent is probably safer, I don't think that it can solve my issue. Actually I was talking about having 20% failure on the exact same element that usually works... Randomly.

Comment: @user2747408 This shouldn't be the case. If you're experiencing such issues try switching the jQuery version to see whether this affects it.

Comment: Changing jQuery version didn't help. But I think you are right, this is not possible. So I'm starting to think about another cause than jquery, maybe css... Thanks anyway for helping. I'm accepting your answer because you provide the only possible explanation from the elements I provided, this could help someone.